# Live connect SDK REST request for updating token

Tags: c#, rest, oauth-2.0, liveconnect

I'm trying to update token, but I get error "The remote server returned an error: (400) Bad Request."
My code is:

```
public static object Refresh_token(string client_id, string redirect_uri, string client_secret, string refresh_token, string scope)
{
    var requestUrl = new StringBuilder("https://login.live.com/oauth20_token.srf");
    requestUrl.Append("?grant_type=refresh_token");
    requestUrl.AppendFormat("&client_id={0}", client_id);
    requestUrl.AppendFormat("&redirect_uri={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(redirect_uri));
    requestUrl.AppendFormat("&client_secret={0}", HttpUtility.UrlEncode(client_secret));
    requestUrl.AppendFormat("&refresh_token={0}", refresh_token);       

    WebRequest request = HttpWebRequest.Create(requestUrl.ToString());
    request.Method = "GET";       
    request.ContentType = "application/x-www.form-urlencoded;charset=UTF-8";
    WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();

    using (var reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
    {
        var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Offline_access>(json);
    }
}
```

If I send it from browser I get

```
{"error":"invalid_scope","error_description":"The provided request must include a 'scope' input parameter."}
```

I tried to do it with POST, but it was the same problem. 
Have some ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the spec changed on the web server side and it's expecting you to send a scope parameter.  I don't know what the scope parameter is and what you need to supply to it but essentially you'll need to add a line for the requestUrl to add it.

```
requestUrl.AppendFormat("&scope={0}", {whatever value the scope is suppose to be});
```

Comment: What error message does it return if you supply the scope parameter.  Does it still say bad request must supply a scope parameter or does it say something else, like the scope parameter is invalid.

Comment: It says parameter is invalid.

Comment: Based on the the Live Connect spec it seems you request is correct.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243647.aspx#request.  It does seem to indicate that it should be a POST rather than a GET but you've already tried that.  Perhaps there is an issue with the initial authorization and the returned error message is based on that rather than what it's telling you.

Comment: There does seem to be a C# live connect c# api that could be helpful or an option depending on your context.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/live/hh243641.aspx

Comment: I had different scopes in my request and in Skydrive access.